# Binding the ActionBar Tabs to a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I am trying to bind the `ActionBar Tabs` to a `ViewPager`. At the very beginning I created two separate projects for `ActionBar Tabs` and `ViewPager`, and they were working fine. When trying to bind the to each other, according to the code below, the `ViewPager` comply to the `TabListener`, in other sense, when I touch an `ActionBar Tab` the `ViewPager` change accordingly and display the respective `View`.For an example, I have three `Tabs`, when touching the `Tab` number two, the `ViewPager` displays the respective page number two. and so on.

But the `ActionBar Tabs` do not obey the `ViewPager`, in other sense, when swiping the screen to move to the next page of the `ViewPager`, the `ViewPager` shows the respective `View` BUT the `ActionBar Tab` does not change its current selected state according to the current `ViewPager`'s selected `View`. For an example, when swiping to to the `ViewPage` number three, the `ViewPager` displays its respected `View` which is number three, BUT, the current selected `ActionBar Tab` does not change to be number three. I could be accessing `ViewPage` three while the highlighted `Tab` is number one.

I hope I explained the problem clearly.

***MainActivity***

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private MyTabsPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private ActionBar mActionBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<Fragment> mFragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    mFragList.add(new Fragment01());
    mFragList.add(new Fragment02());
    mFragList.add(new Fragment03());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mPagerAdapter = new MyTabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragList);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    for(int i=0; i<mFragList.size(); i++) {
        mActionBar.addTab(mActionBar.newTab().setText("Fragment0"+(i+1)).setTabListener(this));         
    }
}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(arg0.getPosition());
    //mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

***MyTabsPagerAdapter***

```
public class MyTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

List<Fragment> mFragList;

public MyTabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> mFragList) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.mFragList = mFragList;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.mFragList.get(arg0);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.mFragList.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a listener for when the viewpager changes for example,

```
 mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });
```

This waits for the viewpager to change and when it does, it sets the actionbar position equal to the position you moved the viewpager to.

Comment: Thank you I have been trying for 2 weeks, and really have found this listener is mentioned in an tutorial. now it is working